# Elasticsearch sort field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have this field mapping

```
    "my_field":{
         "long"
   }
```

This field can take only four values "1,2,3,4" . 
And I want to sort my documents by this field "my_field", in this order: first documents displayed to be where my_field is 1,3 OR 4 , and where my_field=2 to be displayed last .

I've already tried to do something to rescore documents where my_field =2 but it doesn't work properly .

```
 "rescore": [
    {
        "query": {
            "rescore_query": {
                "match": {
                    "my_field": {
                        "query": 2,
                        "slop": 1
                    }
                }
            },
            "query_weight": 0.0001,
            "rescore_query_weight": 0.0001
        }
    }
],
```

How can I get results order by my_field values like follows : 1,3,4,2

Mapping:

```
          {
            "index_name" : {
            "mappings" : {
            "type_name" : {
            "properties" : {
            "address" : {
            "type" : "string"
            },
            "country_id" : {
            "type" : "long"
            },
            "county_id" : {
            "type" : "long"
            },
            "created" : {
            "type" : "long"
            },
             "my_field":{
                   "long"
             }
            }
}
}
```

And this is the query  :

```
    {
    "fields": [
        "_source"
    ],
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "my_field": [
               1,
                2
            ]
        }
    },
    "rescore": [
        {
            "query": {
                "rescore_query": {
                    "match": {
                        "my_field": {
                            "query": 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                "query_weight": 0.1,
                "rescore_query_weight": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "query": {
                "rescore_query": {
                    "match": {
                        "my_field": {
                            "query": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                "query_weight": 1,
                "rescore_query_weight": 33
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've posted here just my attempt increase score for my_field where value is 1 and decrase for value 2

Comment: Can you post the mapping for this index and maybe some more from the query itself (you only posted the "rescore" attempt)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to query? You only want to sort the documents or you are looking for something else, as well? (for example, searching by address and sorting the resulting documents by "my_field")

Comment: I have already defined a query  and I want my documents to be sorted like by "my_field" values -  1,3,4,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider "sorting" the documents by the score ES gives them when searching. If your are only interested in sorting the documents and, even if you have something else in your query (for example, you search some addresses), I would give the elements of the query for each "my_field" value different `boost` values and for those elements of the query that don't interest me in the sorting process - a `constant_score`:

```
{
  "fields": ["_source"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "constant_score": {
          "query": {"terms": {"my_field": [1, 2, 3, 4] }}}}
      ],
      "should": [
        { "match": { "my_field" : {"query": 1, "boost" : 8}}},
        { "match": { "my_field" : {"query": 3, "boost" : 8}}},
        { "match": { "my_field" : {"query": 4, "boost" : 8}}},
        { "match": { "my_field" : {"query": 2, "boost" : 1}}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above I am giving a constant score value (defaults to 1) to everything I don't want to interfere with the scoring calculations. And for my_field" values I'm using a `match` for each (knowing that each document has that field populated) but with a different `boost` value. 1, 3 and 4 are treated equally (giving them a large `boost` of 8) and 2 is treated normally (`boost` value of 1).

Comment: Thank you for your reply . This is working as I expected . I'm trying to combine this with my queries

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result I expected like follows :

```
{
    "fields": [
        "_source"
    ],
    "size": 20,
    "query": {
        ...
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "my_field": {
                "order": "asc",
                "nested_filter": {
                    "terms": {
                        "my_field": [
                            1,
                            3,
                            4
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now results where my_field is equal 2 are listed last  .